# php cURL Error:Illegal characters found in URL

Tags: php, api, curl

Hi i have a problem in retrieving data from a `API` called `healthOs`.

i'm getting

> cURL Error:Illegal characters found in URL

here i want fetch the data using `PHP`  here is doccumentation:https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/2641261/healthos/6nATBN9#aa477f59-954c-744e-38dc-4e12a833fb70

**i have tried this code :**

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.healthos.co
/api/v1/autocomplete/medicines/brands/CROCIN 125 MG SUSPENSION",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization" => "12b570970d786ebf07c85496f5d2a7212fca81799c93379c43066206b6780885"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

**here is my 100% genuine credentials:**

**client id :**

```
faf4ad2651a7906fee8fab4c682ecc2721e16cc05771d8b32c807050ff621972
```

**Client Secret:**

```
eb6731289c24359adcc76a98ed643de0b6f48526a4d56071d9c9cdb3656c3a9a
```

**Access Token:**  `12b570970d786ebf07c85496f5d2a7212fca81799c93379c43066206b6780885`

[image]

**please refer doccumentation**:https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/2641261/healthos/6nATBN9#aa477f59-954c-744e-38dc-4e12a833fb70

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## My HealthOS API Example for PHP

Their API has sample code, but it's not for PHP, so it just takes some work to translate into PHP:

```
<?php

// POST Request Access Token 

$fields = array(
    'grant_type' => "client_credentials",
    'client_id' => "faf4ad2651a7906fee8fab4c682ecc2721e16cc05771d8b32c807050ff621972",
    'client_secret' => "eb6731289c24359adcc76a98ed643de0b6f48526a4d56071d9c9cdb3656c3a9a",
    'scope' => "public read write"
);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.healthos.co/api/v1/oauth/token.json',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($fields),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "content-type: application/json"
  )
));

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$response = json_decode( $json_response, TRUE );
$access_token = $response['access_token'];


// GET Search Medicines

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.healthos.co/api/v1/autocomplete/medicines/brands/" . urlencode('CROCIN 125 MG SUSPENSION'),
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Bearer " . $access_token
  )
));

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$response = json_decode( $json_response, TRUE );

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $response );
echo '</pre>';
```

Notice how there are two requests, one for the authorization, and a second for the medicine search. I get these results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => CROCIN 125 MG SUSPENSION
            [form] => ML of suspension
            [standardUnits] => 1
            [packageForm] => bottle
            [price] => 37.77
            [size] => 60 ML suspension
            [manufacturer] => Glaxo SmithKline Pharmaceuticals Ltd
            [constituents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Paracetamol
                            [strength] => 125 mg
                        )

                )

            [schedule] => Array
                (
                    [category] => OTC
                    [label] => It can be sold without a prescription
                )

            [id] => 586ab09f91c126fe056b693f
            [medicine_id] => 63GIV
            [search_score] => 2.097369
        )

)
```

Comment: your code seems to be working as in dashboard there is a request for `crocin..`.   WHEN i tried i'm getting blank screen without any error. why?

Comment: Did you run it all by itself? No other code? You may need to display errors and turn on error reporting in PHP to figure that out. What version of PHP? Do you have curl enabled? Also, I took out the error checking, because I was just trying to get it to work. It's possible that the API is not responding, or has banned you because of requests coming from all over the world. I don't know.

Comment: Actually, it is still running fine for me. I am on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine, with PHP 5.5.9. I'll go to my PHP 7 machine and check there.

Comment: thanks @Brain Gottier, thanks for the effort, because of your code  got some understanding. thanks once again

Comment: Your welcome. By the way, I'm now on a machine with PHP 7, and it works fine here too.

Comment: i have one doubt could you please clarify, how this line is interpreted by server `  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Bearer " . $access_token
  )
` is it a key value pair or something else.

Comment: cant we define like this    `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization:"  => $access_token
  )`

Comment: Depends on the version of PHP. I seem to recall that I had to do that once. Try both ways and use whatever works :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove new line from URL.

Change

```
CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.healthos.co
/api/v1/autocomplete/medicines/brands/CROCIN 125 MG SUSPENSION",
```

to

```
CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.healthos.co/api/v1/autocomplete/medicines/brands/CROCIN 125 MG SUSPENSION",
```

Comment: i don't see any  change, what was wrong with original one?

Comment: @EaB You have new line after `www.healthos.co` remove that new line

Answer (score 1):

#### Try this

- I added `urlencode()` to keep url intact.
- I removed new line from original url.

```
$curl = curl_init();
    $url = "http://www.healthos.com/api/v1/autocomplete/medicines/brands/CROCIN 125 MG SUSPENSION";
    $endpoint = urlencode( $url );

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
 // CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.healthos.co/api/v1/autocomplete/medicines/brands/CROCIN 125 MG SUSPENSION",
  CURLOPT_URL => $endpoint,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization" => "12b570970d786ebf07c85496f5d2a7212fca81799c93379c43066206b6780885"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The URL is not correct kindly change the URL as following one

www.healthos.co is not a valid one. change into **www.healthos.com**

```
CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.healthos.com/api/v1/autocomplete/medicines/brands/CROCIN 125 MG SUSPENSION",
```

Comment: please refer their doccumentation:https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/2641261/healthos/6nATBN9#aa477f59-954c-744e-38dc-4e12a833fb70

Comment: Why you told its invalid url. `www.healthos.co` is valid. And your suggested URL invalid